# Operating System & Grub in 2 USB Sticks - Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, usb, windows, virtualbox, grub

I tried very hard on this one, but nothing is coming up,

Basically what I am trying to do is as follows:

When starting my machine before the Windows pop up, the Bios call one USB that holds the GRUB that will start the other USB that holds the Operating system.

I am trying to set up via VirtualBox.

I tried to follow the Arch Wiki also some good tutorials like: http://valleycat.org/linux/arch-usb.html and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RsrPrA8NJHk&t=376s

However couldn't figure out what steps I am missing, so I will try to bring shortly what I am doing:

Open VM with 2 USB sticks `/dev/sdb` `/dev/sdc`.

In `/dev/sdb` I am installing the EFI and in `/dev/sdc` the Arch.

Here is the following steps:

```
fdisk /dev/sdb
n
EF00
w
mkfs.fat -F32 /dev/sdb1


fdisk /dev/sdc
n
w
mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdc1
mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt

mkdir /mnt/boot
mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/boot

pacstrap /mnt ...
genfstab -U /mnt ...

arch-chroot /mnt
...
pacman -S grub efibootmgr
grub-install ??? (I probably having issues here)
grub-mkconfig -o ...
```

Any Ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: `When starting my machine before the Windows pop up, the Bios call one USB`   ... there is no "before the Windows pop up"  ... you either boot from USB drive or from one of the partitions ... windows does not sit and wait for the USB drive to somehow finish its boot

Comment: Is your problem that you can't get a bootable grub onto the USB, or you can boot into the grub but can't get it to boot the Linux on the other USB. Also, out of curiosity, are these USB sticks or external hard drives?

Comment: I guess is the second option, since yesterday I had some grub menu telling me that I could only use a few shell commands. And is 2 USB sticks. Thanks for the clarification @jsotola.

Comment: Sorry, first option.