# How do I install grub on a disk drive using a UUID?

Tags: grub2, uuid

On my Arch Linux I am trying to install GRUB as follows:

```
grub-install /dev/sda
```

Instead of `/dev/sda` to do with UUID.

However two points to bring up:

1. I cannot find a UUID for `/dev/sda` only for `/dev/sda1` or `/dev/sda2`
2. When trying to install on UUID of `/dev/sda1` for example it says:

   > ```
   > *' error cannot find a grub drive for UUID. check your device.map '*
   > ```

By the way also the `device.map` does not exists under `/boot/grub/device.map`

How to do that?

Ps. Edited:
Thank you for **bey0nd** helping me finding out the UUID for /dev/sda. However I am still having issues with number two.

What I am trying to do is the following:

"`/dev/sdX` X is the drive (letter) on which you want GRUB to write the boot information. Normally users should not include a partition number, which would produce an error message as the command would attempt to write the information to a partition.

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sdX
```

This will rewrite the MBR information to point to the current installation and rewrite some GRUB 2 files (which are already working). Since it isn't done during execution of the previous command, running sudo update-grub after the install will ensure GRUB 2's menu is up-to-date."

This shows how to reinstall GRUB, but the main point in which I want to point out is that I am trying to install the Operating System in `/dev/sdb` device and the GRUB loader in `/dev/sda`. The effect it will couse is that, the only way to start `/dev/sdb` is if I have `/dev/sda` plugged in as well. And the reason why I want to do with `UUID` and not the name `/dev/sda` is because sometimes the names `/dev/sdX` are changed from PC to PC.

Ps. Edited 2:
I don't know if it makes more clear, but I need to separate the boot-loader (USB1) from the Operating System (USB2). Just didn't figure out how yet.

Comment: A UUID is a property of a file-system. You cannot really install the GRUB boot-loaded on a file-system. A disk drive does not have a UUID. Please clarify what you want to achieve.

Comment: Hello, may I ask why are you trying this, is that pure mind-exercise, or is there an actual usefulness behind scenes? To be honest, I've never installed GRUB2 on my own, I know it's there, of course, and what it is doing. You are installing it **to what end?** I did read your edit now, just woken up, and still don't get it.

Comment: Also, _"When trying to install on UUID of `/dev/sda1`..."_, you have a partition NUMBER there, you cannot install your bootloader on a partition. Confusing question, really.

Comment: Maybe this could help understanding (however I am not using UEFI system). https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/567072/operating-system-grub-in-2-usb-sticks-arch-linux?noredirect=1#comment1054538_567072

Comment: The idea is to not allow anyone access my linux without having both USB sticks.

Comment: hoooold, the PTUUID is *not* the UUID of the HDD (e.g. /dev/sda) but the UUID of the _partition table_!! To my knowledge, there is no UUID for an entire HDD.

Comment: You will get what you want if your grub can be "spread out" across two disks??

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you should be able to find the UUID of the partition table (PTUUID) of `/dev/sda` with the following command:

```
sudo blkid /dev/sda
```

I've never tried to use this PTUUID to install `grub` an a disk drive. Therefore, I can't tell you if that works or if your disk is *clean* after this.
edit: clarification of PTUUID <> partition table.
edit2: I did some more research and the PTUUID is *not* what you want to install grub on!!
As there is *no* UUID for an entire HDD your first point has to be answered:  *You can't find a UUID for /dev/sda as there is none.*
As for your second point, you can (or could?) install GRUB into a partition.  There is a good explanation on how to do this if you follow this [link](https://github.com/alberthdev/alberthdev-misc/wiki/Installing-GRUB2-to-a-Partition)

Comment: noop, if I remeber correctly then the UUID relates to the filesystem on a partition, PARTUUID to the partition itself, and the PTUUID to the (GPT) partition tabel (PT) of the HDD.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me figure out the PTUUID. However I am still getting the error with number 2. It might be the syntax: (i.e) grub-install 989573d5-37e7-437a-b680-9410f7234a94. What I am trying to do I'll be editing in the question.

Answer (score -1):

Once installed to the MBR, GRUB does not care about which *number* the drive had during install time. GRUB stage 1 loads GRUB stage 2, which – as far as I know – **must** reside on the same disk. The kernel however can be on a another drive and the partition on that drive can be identified via UUID. Let's assume your Linux is currently booted from `sdb` and you have prepared an auxiliary partition `sdax`:

```
mount /dev/sdax /mnt
grub-install /dev/sda --boot-directory=/mnt
grub-mkconfig -o /mnt/grub/grub.cfg
```

This will install GRUB stage 1 to the MBR of `sda`, stage 2 and the configuration data go to the file-system on `sdax`.

Using this for security is a **horrible** idea. Security by obscurity does not work. Anyone with a Super GRUB2 disk will be able to boot your system.

Comment: Ok, so basically I cannot separate the grub from my USB. You mentioned, let's assume you Linux is currently booted from sdb and on sda you have /mnt. Therefore without sdb, sda won't work. So how can I perform the sdb part boot-loader you just mentioned?

Comment: `grub-mkconfig` will create a grub configuration which identifies the currently active kernel's partition via UUID. That is unless `GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true` is set in `/etc/default/grub`. `sdb` is never mentioned explicitly – which is what I understand you asked for.

Comment: The downvotes make me assume I still do not understand the question or the intentions. Please clarify.

Comment: Well if the guy just down-vote without telling why is really hard to know where are the mistake.